# Moments of a shifted Binomial random variable

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

does someone know how to calculate the following expectation?

Assume $B$ binomial distributed with parameter $N\in \mathbb{N}$ and $p\in [0,1]$. Further let $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Define $Y:= B-x$

$\mathbb{E}[(Y)^n]$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Im actually interested in the case $n=4$.

Comment: If we shift a random variables in each $\omega \in \Omega$ by the same value $x$ then it should not have an impact on its "behaviour". So I guess we have for higher moments a different deterministic shift as in the variance. I struggle to do the calculations for higher moments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the MGF of $B-x$ is given by
$$M_{B-x}(\xi)=E[e^{\xi (B-x)}]=e^{-\xi x}E[e^{\xi B}]=e^{-\xi x}M_B(\xi)$$
From this you can calculate any moment.